# How to Unit Test Repository Pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, authentication, moq

I would like to test my authentication controller, I have tried several ways to get this done. I keep having to deal with dependency injection and that's where things go wrong. How can I best test my controller unit? I already tried it with Moq.

This is my Authentication Controller:

```
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Models;
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Models.Requests;
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Models.Responses;
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Services.Authenticators;
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Services.PasswordHashers;
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Services.RefreshTokenRepositories;
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Services.TokenValidators;
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Services.UserRepositories;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AuthenticationServerAPI.Controllers
{
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {

        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private readonly IPasswordHasher _passwordHasher;
        private readonly Authenticator _authenticator;
        private readonly RefreshTokenValidator _refreshTokenValidator;
        private readonly IRefreshTokenRepository _refreshTokenRepository;

        public AuthenticationController(IUserRepository userRepository, IPasswordHasher passwordHasher, Authenticator authenticator, RefreshTokenValidator refreshTokenValidator, IRefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _passwordHasher = passwordHasher;
            _authenticator = authenticator;
            _refreshTokenValidator = refreshTokenValidator;
            _refreshTokenRepository = refreshTokenRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterRequest registerRequest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequestModelState();
            }
            if (registerRequest.Password != registerRequest.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                return BadRequest(new ErrorResponse("Passowrd does not match confirm password"));
            }
            User existingUserByEmail = await _userRepository.GetByEmail(registerRequest.Email);
            if (existingUserByEmail != null) 
            {
                return Conflict(new ErrorResponse("Email already exists."));
            }
            User existingUserByUsername = await _userRepository.GetByUsername(registerRequest.Username);
            if (existingUserByUsername != null)
            {
                return Conflict(new ErrorResponse("Username already exists."));
            }

            string passwordHash = _passwordHasher.HashPassword(registerRequest.Password);

            User registrationUser = new User()
            {
                Email = registerRequest.Email,
                Username = registerRequest.Username,
                PasswordHash = passwordHash
            };

            await _userRepository.Create(registrationUser);
            return Ok();     
        }

        [HttpPost("login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginRequest loginRequest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequestModelState();
            }
            User user = await _userRepository.GetByUsername(loginRequest.Username);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            bool isCorrectPassword = _passwordHasher.VerifyPassword(loginRequest.Password, user.PasswordHash);
            if (!isCorrectPassword) 
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            AuthenticatedUserResponse response = await _authenticator.Authenticate(user);
            return Ok(response);    
        }

        [HttpPost("refresh")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Refresh([FromBody] RefreshRequest refreshRequest) 
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequestModelState();
            }

            bool isValidRefreshToken = _refreshTokenValidator.Validate(refreshRequest.RefreshToken);
            if (!isValidRefreshToken) 
            {
                return BadRequest(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Refresh Token."));
            }

            RefreshToken refreshTokenDTO = await _refreshTokenRepository.GetByToken(refreshRequest.RefreshToken);
            if (refreshTokenDTO == null)
            {
                return NotFound(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Refresh Token."));
            }

            await _refreshTokenRepository.Delete(refreshTokenDTO.Id);

            User user = await _userRepository.GetById(refreshTokenDTO.UserId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound(new ErrorResponse("User not found."));
            }
            AuthenticatedUserResponse response = await _authenticator.Authenticate(user);
            return Ok(response);
        }

        [Authorize]
        [HttpDelete("logout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            string rawUserId = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue("id");
            if (!Guid.TryParse(rawUserId, out Guid userId))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }
            await _refreshTokenRepository.DeleateAll(userId);
            return NoContent();
        }

        private IActionResult BadRequestModelState()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> errorMessages = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
            return BadRequest(new ErrorResponse(errorMessages));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test the functionality from my database repository like register a user en logging in the user.

This is my database repository:

```
using AuthenticationServerAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AuthenticationServerAPI.Services.UserRepositories
{
    public class DatabaseUserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly AuthenticationDbContext _context;

        public DatabaseUserRepository(AuthenticationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        } 

        public async Task<User> Create(User user)
        {
            _context.Users.Add(user);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return user;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetByEmail(string email)
        {
            return await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == email);
        }

        public async Task<User> GetById(Guid userId)
        {
            return await _context.Users.FindAsync(userId);
        }

        public async Task<User> GetByUsername(string username)
        {
            return await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Username == username);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Unit Testing this makes little sense. In the end you could only test if it is implemented the way you did or end up testing EntityFramework ... makes no sense. What you need here is an End-To-End Test. So, you need a Test Database, that will be created, prepared and modified by your tests and validated against.

Comment: You can take a look on Integration tests

Comment: @Fildor Why would it make little sense? In my opinion it seems perfectly fine to test. As example; for the `Register` function you could easily test whether the hash function is called and the result of that is passed on as password or that the expected status codes are returned for the various situations.

Comment: @404 What do you gain from the knowledge that the hashfunction has been called if you are not testing a conditional? Every call to `Register` must call the hash function (given the tests before the call pass). So, testing _if_ it gets called merely proves that it has been used in the implementation. It doesn't prove that it actually works and it doesn't prove that the hashed value ends up in the db. So, it makes _little_ sense to me. It would, though, if requirements needed a specific implementation to be called, which I doubt is the case here.

Comment: @Fildor It proves that your controller properly hashes the password and doesn't pass a plain text password to the database as example. It's purely about testing the code inside the controller in isolaton and not the code of repositories/services. Albeit the code is quite minimal there's value to it and it's also what the OP requests.

Comment: @404 _"It proves that your controller properly hashes the password and doesn't pass a plain text password to the database"_ - No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Fildor In the context of an isolated unit test you can assume that your dependencies function as documented.

Comment: @404 Exactly. That's the point. Now, what's the benefit of that test? Especially if OP wants to test the _repository_ (as he writes in the question). - Oh, wait. I am reading again, and I think OP is mixing both tests...

Comment: @Tom _"

I would like to test my authentication controller"_ vs _"I want to test the functionality from my database repository"_ - which one? Those should be separate tests! (For _unit_ tests. Of course, you can do integration and/or e2e Tests.)